# HTML Save as PDF 2 Pages

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have a button to print my html as PDF. Problem is I need it to print in two pages. Different browsers are messing it up and not printing 2nd page right. How do I specific page 2 with my code..

```js
       function printPageArea(areaID){
       var printContent = document.getElementById(areaID);
       var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'width=830,height=792');
       WinPrint.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
       WinPrint.document.close();
       WinPrint.focus();
       WinPrint.print();
       WinPrint.close();
        }
```

```html
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="position: relative;left: 0;top: 50px;" onClick="printPageArea('printableArea')"><button class="custom" style="width:auto!important;">Download PDF</button></a>


     <div class="content-wrap-consent" id="printableArea">

     <div class="page-one">
     Page One
     </div>


    <div class="page-two">
    Page two
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have given hard coded  height and width to open a window.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `@media print` in css,

Below are some of the links,

[Create print styles using CSS3 @media queries](https://benfrain.com/create-print-styles-using-css3-media-queries/)

[CSS Printing - @media Rule](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_printing.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `page-break-before` or `page-break-after` to insert a page break before or after an element, respectively.

```
@media print {
    .page-two {
        page-break-before: always;
    }
}
```